# curl output JSON Parsing data

Tags: curl, awk, sed, grep, cut

My Code :

```
curl  -i -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'      -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8'           -H 'cookie: mcd=3; ig_cb=1; mid=W4PfJAAEAAE1DGjnE45SEwFztzbV; datr=21W0WyyVPxIwsY2Jhsnrt-69; csrftoken=6JeciuKt08Paw4WtaDtQtXoZDQZi4tzr; rur=ATN; urlgen="{\"x.x.x.x\": 31549}:1gBa8v:CMSLGwfUFGiJZYOY-Rj6KLIRPmQ"'                       -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1'                       -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'     'https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=blended&query=Mehran&rank_token=0.6063273796342663&include_reel=false'
```

My Output GET Response with cURL is :

```
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
vary: Accept-Language, Cookie, Accept-Encoding
content-language: en
date: Sun, 14 Oct 2018 08:25:46 GMT
content-length: 31852
strict-transport-security: max-age=60
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-security-policy-report-only: report-uri https://www.instagram.com/security/csp_report/; default-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; img-src https: data: blob:; font-src https: data:; media-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.fbcdn.net; manifest-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; script-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com wss://www.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob:; style-src 'self' https://*.www.instagram.com https://www.instagram.com 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://graph.instagram.com https://*.graph.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://api.instagram.com wss://www.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd; worker-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; frame-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://staticxx.facebook.com https://www.facebook.com https://web.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://m.facebook.com; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests
set-cookie: rur=FTW; Domain=.instagram.com; HttpOnly; Path=/; Secure
set-cookie: urlgen="{\"151.242.133.81\": 31549\054 \"168.63.11.202\": 8075}:1gBbic:EcWDelkIwvmXk_7wBMpa3Pqy-PY"; Domain=.instagram.com; HttpOnly; Path=/; Secure
set-cookie: csrftoken=6JeciuKt08Paw4WtaDtQtXoZDQZi4tzr; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Sun, 13-Oct-2019 08:25:46 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure


{"users": [{"position": 0, "user": {"pk": "7068661926", "username": "xtentacionm", "full_name": "xxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e5ae2f4ce5ada71de3fc628c6d8033a2/5C4DB71F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/36161424_266603240557186_2523081505857601536_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1821571871650150859_7068661926", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 3897, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "3897 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 15, "user": {"pk": "7660264043", "username": "bfbluefilmfucksexdesi", "full_name": "Xxx sex video bf blue film", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/10cded9657ba95d42a7e06a94d3a2bd3/5C4B8FC4/t51.2885-19/s150x150/31166787_900587163447531_3996875657756803072_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1771613578445630466_7660264043", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 5385, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "5385 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 17, "user": {"pk": "6387774601", "username": "fitworkuat", "full_name": "xxxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/24eab8f4d5b3f923cc58d0a953e90e59/5C46F240/t51.2885-19/s150x150/36085249_1884978924891480_6566594499789717504_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1816746776683509238_6387774601", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 12229, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "12.2k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 18, "user": {"pk": "6908360373", "username": "xxculitos_bueno", "full_name": "xxx porno", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/062bff676229e61a83c76a7e6e98f2d9/5C3D7D85/t51.2885-19/s150x150/26068972_256260961575335_3893220058041679872_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1690241878980429125_6908360373", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 9988, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "9988 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 19, "user": {"pk": "8280627508", "username": "fucking_and_sexx", "full_name": "Xxx_porno", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/95247da3f7ab1db0b05822e49031767d/5C513328/t51.2885-19/s150x150/37908766_443618249455456_7866300789524791296_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1841629881038690953_8280627508", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 9723, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "9723 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 20, "user": {"pk": "6993484722", "username": "xnxx_video_16", "full_name": "xxx_sexo_pics", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/8acf89eacbdf5783ec4d939b2dfde406/5C5E4437/t51.2885-19/s150x150/29090390_161031378044516_7168619846626705408_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1740681803473426268_6993484722", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 12504, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "12.5k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 21, "user": {"pk": "7458627907", "username": "sex_xxnx4501", "full_name": "xxxx.nx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a3cd1bf57eca98ddf990f9bd711081ec/5C44972C/t51.2885-19/s150x150/30890626_1283491125119689_1463123447386210304_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1771615240708263556_7458627907", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 5694, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "5694 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 22, "user": {"pk": "7978168725", "username": "sexyest_bbw", "full_name": "xxxxxxvidoes", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a7ec0072e98469376bcc6066bf861721/5C565DDE/t51.2885-19/s150x150/35001699_1764230423653288_2085794384187490304_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1798412345943207161_7978168725", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 3769, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "3769 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 23, "user": {"pk": "3457885346", "username": "xyz0009___", "full_name": "xxx", "is_private": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frt3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a8539c22ed9fec8e1c43b538b1ebfd1d/5C5A1A7A/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": true, "follower_count": 227850, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "227k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 24, "user": {"pk": "3966638792", "username": "p.o.r.n.o.and.x.x.x", "full_name": "\u2b50\u2b50porno_xxx\u2b50\u2b50", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/aa2b0fcf1c72b1b979a3e67dcbcfe173/5C4C7B3A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/25005660_343283069474076_6513919895590141952_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1436578521149112140_3966638792", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 17143, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "17.1k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 25, "user": {"pk": "8077761268", "username": "misculos_y_cosas_sex", "full_name": "porno xxx sex", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frt3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a8539c22ed9fec8e1c43b538b1ebfd1d/5C5A1A7A/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": true, "follower_count": 4946, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "4946 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 26, "user": {"pk": "6894879260", "username": "gajas_nuas._", "full_name": "xxx. xxxxxxxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/f78a3e08bfe72410343a6257f2c937d0/5C4BBD89/t51.2885-19/s150x150/26157876_955229157965255_5095242474884956160_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1688567785385833245_6894879260", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 5780, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "5780 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 27, "user": {"pk": "7661293220", "username": "hotty_update", "full_name": "XXX VIDEO DM ME \ud83d\udd35", "is_private": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6a571edc260d291c0019b6420107bbac/5C574C75/t51.2885-19/s150x150/42593429_240353946635049_5063694174864277504_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1887693494074423778_7661293220", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 27028, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "27k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 28, "user": {"pk": "8914052333", "username": "sexo.x_abc", "full_name": "Xxx Sexo", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/bdb970655ed76e417d5818682394fcbc/5C5CEED4/t51.2885-19/s150x150/38817423_2184773555126431_3989413474202550272_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1851377199761641029_8914052333", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 1187, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "1187 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 29, "user": {"pk": "2492746597", "username": "ass_bundas", "full_name": "xxx photo", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/146cb512a49304799eed219e48330219/5C408ABD/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13285377_235618950148202_820929696_a.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1258398566432962874_2492746597", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 31336, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "31.3k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 30, "user": {"pk": "7803495494", "username": "adult.videossss", "full_name": "XXX Videos", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/47bb53fa4867052b6ba052eab5f884e0/5C3C6CAC/t51.2885-19/s150x150/32379781_942286609286034_7157731782408798208_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1783874365534706767_7803495494", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 6850, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "6850 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 31, "user": {"pk": "6408745220", "username": "divasfigures", "full_name": "slayers xxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6d9ee98d81190dd095de0c283c74504c/5C6224D4/t51.2885-19/s150x150/41307698_470872870078786_3183888780129992704_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1870546630505421696_6408745220", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 34361, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "34.3k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 32, "user": {"pk": "2531089703", "username": "v.i.d.e.o.s_x.x.x", "full_name": "Videos XXX", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/8ece0f483c1fb9abb8f82087d8672987/5C5CD676/t51.2885-19/s150x150/25016338_1440997139332531_4161944977657561088_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1674552376650044642_2531089703", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 2390, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "2390 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 33, "user": {"pk": "7699639177", "username": "video_s_e_x_y", "full_name": "sexy xxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/c8589ab92a0d53c1296f3bafaab9c169/5C52A197/t51.2885-19/s150x150/31729680_622186748142780_6656343094184640512_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1774785536634872499_7699639177", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 4836, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "4836 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 34, "user": {"pk": "5488402780", "username": "xx_xx_seks", "full_name": "\u0445\u0445\u0445\u0445\u0445\u0445", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/656a4c8c5d53711a70ebce118d021fbd/5C5AE422/t51.2885-19/s150x150/18579631_419953981719078_3182656459523489792_a.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1518881848414038877_5488402780", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 2956, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "2956 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 35, "user": {"pk": "238092556", "username": "youngellens", "full_name": "XXX\ud83e\udd40..", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/4f1a536d9d42eb860e039833f9f327c0/5C564F3C/t51.2885-19/s150x150/39506730_2182423255329524_1302873351374503936_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1857640846560705218_238092556", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 70029, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "70k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 36, "user": {"pk": "7355617135", "username": "galeryangels", "full_name": "Gairah Remaja XXX", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/df83f12981e41451a47bfa74fb340b70/5C5C7787/t51.2885-19/s150x150/42847983_301165177379354_5295148772739776512_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1885456700993700560_7355617135", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 10922, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "10.9k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 37, "user": {"pk": "703043296", "username": "xxxfanzine", "full_name": "xXx Fanzine", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/f57a4eb04608c43b5db7386c09cdc430/5C5D884F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/16788699_323659674697446_8634996267883167744_a.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1451955599973528478_703043296", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 12093, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "12k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 38, "user": {"pk": "1451025673", "username": "v.stormxx", "full_name": "Victoria_Storm xxx", "is_private": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/28330f676a619a9642bcbb40ffb90b44/5C4A98FF/t51.2885-19/s150x150/42150450_180053996218974_7357785681109712896_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1886769455741322400_1451025673", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 1844, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "1844 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 39, "user": {"pk": "7704650714", "username": "worlddvirals", "full_name": "XXXTentacion", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/705f832b2c518b7cf4339404c9540856/5C45DF96/t51.2885-19/s150x150/41714083_537266463412204_6719154718850940928_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1877373342812388209_7704650714", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 13792, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "13.7k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 40, "user": {"pk": "744078735", "username": "rameusico", "full_name": "xxxrameus", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ab68a1450c6dfddde024b7b955086a60/5C630107/t51.2885-19/s150x150/39242094_668238583563477_6677197810401542144_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1854549164491483803_744078735", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 5367, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "5367 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 41, "user": {"pk": "7131156204", "username": "veryvare", "full_name": "xxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/eb918d7e8964d16c9c5c8b255805c775/5C463129/t51.2885-19/s150x150/42634332_566569160464888_7702071320413995008_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1884178707327155554_7131156204", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 5371, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "5371 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 42, "user": {"pk": "6299445317", "username": "xvro17x", "full_name": "XXX", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/98813453353849677c829b7b6910db47/5C462264/t51.2885-19/s150x150/38517576_495354537598453_8480994451638976512_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1849161046047063574_6299445317", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 3799, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "3799 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 43, "user": {"pk": "8316360575", "username": "jahsehsbich", "full_name": "xxxtentacion", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a1cbb1f282f71e58cc19db9840032b48/5C427204/t51.2885-19/s150x150/42453302_490008391475215_1741446545166827520_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1879071525652799613_8316360575", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 14219, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "14.2k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 44, "user": {"pk": "6786293330", "username": "xxtentaceon", "full_name": "XXXTENTACION", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/2a9bd66e7d2626c4a92ed0cf543e61ff/5C3FE81A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/26395862_433265990425938_461922259511017472_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1701823209311428459_6786293330", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 42197, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "42.1k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 45, "user": {"pk": "6044855055", "username": "ndugu.lawama__tintinnabulum", "full_name": "xxxx video", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/f3748788ac0558bee482e8ac09f9f941/5C50EF12/t51.2885-19/s150x150/21827329_310017429406726_2811961959669301248_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1608814397172763935_6044855055", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 9616, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "9616 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 46, "user": {"pk": "7317896065", "username": "nsfw_videos", "full_name": "sexy videos/ hot videos/xxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/95580a6ce6e6098c70f35c2d891e5bdf/5C6110A7/t51.2885-19/s150x150/40125559_569497506817961_4095783634982666240_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1742172283625876835_7317896065", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 43668, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "43.6k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 47, "user": {"pk": "5711023711", "username": "clubmasiofficial", "full_name": "Maserati XXX", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/0f002e664810bce68ae1da4e60aef923/5C3C35CD/t51.2885-19/s150x150/19984601_1726371750996589_8811945763677405184_a.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1554866795697372209_5711023711", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 175364, "reel_auto_archive": "off", "byline": "175k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 48, "user": {"pk": "2080536438", "username": "novacanexoxo", "full_name": "model | XXX \ud83d\udc95 adults only \ud83d\udc44\ud83c\udf39", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/18344f09f75b2c4e1e78e46e43867101/5C4ECF67/t51.2885-19/s150x150/37917787_2001398620082549_7100457873825595392_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1838787825706563724_2080536438", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 17401, "reel_auto_archive": "unset", "byline": "17.4k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 49, "user": {"pk": "8231857430", "username": "aaaking33", "full_name": "xxxx---sexy king", "is_private": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a1d7f3f5c4b455b2d570a56cf543818f/5C551310/t51.2885-19/s150x150/38022158_1097969030379696_7999477000840413184_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1840164277479816656_8231857430", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 65, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "65 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 50, "user": {"pk": "8299632075", "username": "putillas_favoritas", "full_name": "modelos xxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/8f5505795f4c93fd6dbbd3f26a175ef2/5C4FF710/t51.2885-19/s150x150/39013979_304128547045743_8131189491596525568_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1854285527403357284_8299632075", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 2659, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "2659 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 51, "user": {"pk": "6246465985", "username": "ashleyadams_official", "full_name": "Ashley Adams xxx", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/1b7c4f0fcba02372ef8dc11d94ab360d/5C3FFAA9/t51.2885-19/s150x150/41092313_1892882554352670_6631454458783989760_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1872954804649828524_6246465985", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 70278, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "70.2k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 52, "user": {"pk": "7275230978", "username": "pattern.x", "full_name": "x x x \u2022 p a t t e r n \u2022 x x x", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/2d383b23603ac6b59a8c5da894443f65/5C53EF1C/t51.2885-19/s150x150/30884579_712115075579493_8063051025151426560_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1766929016773002098_7275230978", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 34053, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "34k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 53, "user": {"pk": "6868294523", "username": "xxtentacionnumb", "full_name": "\ud83d\udd25 Daily XXXTENTACION \ud83d\udd2e", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/dd1342711c1f4f792f8cf89d6ad4b7dd/5C577C11/t51.2885-19/s150x150/43820576_957047761147413_7273570099808698368_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1887116059182399553_6868294523", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 9584, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "9584 followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 54, "user": {"pk": "4175587826", "username": "bobderehrenmann", "full_name": "XXX", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/07426754fd0558566c8213f57cf6deb7/5C59DBA2/t51.2885-19/s150x150/19227244_324860601288530_3312318369683734528_a.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1541358303389201661_4175587826", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 16187, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "16.1k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 55, "user": {"pk": "3663338531", "username": "mizzjadathyck", "full_name": "Mizz Jada Thyck XXX", "is_private": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6b5fe0abef8411dd8beb92bc3ec49ae6/5C5C11B3/t51.2885-19/s150x150/23421670_1742510969154184_6469735561266462720_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1645186754255718085_3663338531", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 193073, "reel_auto_archive": "on", "byline": "193k followers", "mutual_followers_count": 0.0, "unseen_count": 0}}, {"position": 56, "user": {"pk": "5539213762", "username": "jahsehxo", "full_name": "Jah", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/179ff4e77ce16f3b6651739eaca939e8/5C61A148/t51.2885-19/s150x150/42429213_1132979643519727_340172873110913024_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1889708349894065603_5539213762", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "follower_count": 58439, "0.6063273796342663", "clear_client_cache": false, "status": "ok"}
```

I want to use `cut , sed or awk` to show me Output ONLY `Username` IDs if them `"is_private": false`

Output Expected :

xtentacionm

bfbluefilmfucksexdesi

....
(Not include any `"is_private": true`)

Comment: Can you please show us what code you've already written?

Comment: @Corion it simple bash curl -X GET "URL" Code. and output is JSON

Comment: This is not a code writing service. We expect you to have written some code to do the extraction, and to show that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be parsing JSON. This is fairly easy using Perl:

```
perl -MJSON::PP -wle 'print $_->{user}->{username} for grep { !$_->{user}->{is_private}} @{ decode_json(<>)->{users}}'
```

This uses the [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP) module included with your Perl already.

An alternative would be to use the `jq` tool, which allows you to query the JSON in a different way.

Comment: this error appear. malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "HTTP/2 200 \r\n") at -e line 1.

Comment: Then what you are piping in is not JSON. The output you showed in your question is JSON, but the error message indicates you're piping in the complete HTTP response.

Comment: output is complete JSON also HTTP Responde Header, am i should use piping at end of curl , or use perl -MJSON::PP -wle "print $_->{user}->{username} for grep { print $_->{user}->{username} for grep { 'https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=blended&query=Mehran&rank_token=0.6063273796342663&include_reel=false'_->{is_private}} @{ decode_json(<>)->{users}}_->{is_private}} @{ decode_json(<>)->{users}"

 ?

Comment: Why didn't you show that there is a HTTP header in front of the actual response? I'll update my response to also strip eventual HTTP response headers, but you really need to work on how to ask a question.

Comment: sorry, I think it does not matter I Updated Question.  , I use your updated answer I got Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.

Comment: Thanks work nice but it Find all usernames , you used `is_private` , i try to change it `is_private:false` but not work

Comment: No, you toggle the sense of the flag by removing the `!` - but there was a bug in the selection of (non-)private users. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181834/discussion-between-corion-and-mehran-goudarzi).